# Add an action to a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am building a simple app with a table view filled with custom view cells and using a storyboard. I want to add a actions on the cell each time the user tap it.

So far, I tried to create an `IBOutle` to link my cell to my `tableViewController` and add the action manually in the code but each time I try to do it I get an error message saying "Illegal Configuration - cannot have a prototype object as its destination".

The only quick fix I found is to add a `UIButton` with a transparent background and no title which fills in the whole cell and attached the action to it.

Is there any more elegant way to do it?

Comment: What kind of action are you talking about. didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called automatically when you tap on a cell -- you don't need to add anything.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not only is there a more "elegant" solution, but there is also a correct way to do this.You should be using the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method for your cells.

You should read what the [Apple Docs have to say](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

And also, [here is a tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-handle-row-selection-in-uitableview/) on how to use row selection in your tableView.

Answer (score 3):

The elegant solution is to use your table view's delegate method `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and put all your action code there.