# set action for UIButton in customized UITableViewCell which has many other views

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I read below posts:

[How to set Action for UIButton in UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652133/how-to-set-action-for-uibutton-in-uitableviewcell)

[Add an action to a custom UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115028/add-an-action-to-a-custom-uitableviewcell)

But all the solutions do not work for me. I am not sure what I missed;
I have a customized `UITableViewCell` which lives in a xib file, this cell contains a `UIImageView`, `UILabel`, one `UIButton`. I hope to when user click the UIButton, it will delete current item from the list, when user select the row, it will navigate to another page.

What I done : From the asked question above, I create a `UIButton` and addTarget,then add the button into cell with `[cell.contentview addsubview:button]`, the button action can be triggered.

There are some other views, I hope to layout them in xib, then do not need layout with code.

So I create a button in the xib, and call setTarget for this button (outlet in my customized cell class), the button action can not be triggered.

Then I add a `UIview` in the xib as placeholder, and create a new button with code and add the button into the placeholder `UIview`, button action can not be triggered.

So it seems the way to make it work must be:

1. Create a button with code;
2. Add target, then add this button into cell's content view directly;

It seems pretty annoying since I don't want to layout views with code. Do I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add one button in the `contentView` of `UITableViewCell` in the `xib` file and create the outlet in `customCell`. After that change your code of `cellForRowAtIndex` like this.

```
[cell.btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

After that create this `btnTap` method

```
- (void)btnTap:(UIButton*)sender {
     CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*) [[sender superview] superview]; //If you have button inside another view you need to add superView on your hierarchy basis.
     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tblFile indexPathForCell:cell];
     NSLog(@"Row you want to delete - %d",indexPath.row);
}
```

Hope this will help you.